# How to disable click thumbnail product on archives product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i want to disable click our product image on archives product page. so, user only can click from the button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

Comment: i still can click that, i meant in archives product not single product.

Answer (score -1):

```
cursor: default !important;
pointer-events: none !important;
```

Comment: Could you please [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/312618/edit) using the [edit link above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/312618/edit) and add a description of what this is? What it does? Why it's needed? Where to add it? And how it answers the question.